# Angular Unit - Testing (Jasmin Karma) : Error :Cannot find name 'google'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular11

google.directives.ts:-

```
  getAutocompletes(addresstext: ElementRef) {
    const autocomplete = new  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addresstext.nativeElement,
      {
       ...
      });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => 
  {
   ...
  }
```

after testing code in jasmin & karma, I got Error :->
Cannot find name 'google'.

How can I solve this issue for unit testing?
I alreday added "googlemaps" in tsconfig.app.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever change you made for `tsconfig.app.json` for it to work, you have to do the same change to `tsconfig.spec.json` for the unit tests to work.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have another doubt, I called same method ( getAutocompletes) in my info.component.ts file and I wrote unit test case for the same but I am facing error "google is not defined". how can I solve this error?  info.component.ts:-> ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ...
    this.googleComplete.getComplete(this.addresstext);

Comment: That's strange, could it be that `this.googleComplete` is not defined?

Comment: I mentioned everything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176938/angular-unit-testing-jasmine-karma-failed-google-is-not-defined .Please have a look

Comment: By editing the `tsconfig.spec.json` it worked, but isn't there any other solution by which the problem would be solved without editing tsconfig.spec.json file.

Comment: Sorry, no. I believe it is a TypeScript error and that error says it can't find those types.